# how to find a value of a document nested in another document

Tags: mongodb

Hello i'm new to Mongodb and i have a question that i haven't found an answer for it yet.

1. I would like to know how to find all the users that are younger than a certain age. db.getCollection('data').find({age:{$lt:50}})  is not working
2. I would like to know how to Extract all the mails of the users to a csv file.

Regards,

Nati

```
//'data'- is the a document/table

//The data looks like that :

 db.getCollection('data').find({}) : 



        /* 1 */

        {  
        "_id" : "8f911",
            "userDetails" : {        "age" : "19",
                "birthday" : "1996/5/11"
        },
            "username" : "emailemail@do.com"
        }

        /* 2 */

    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Your age field is not numerical thus comparison operators like `$lt` will not work well on string fields.

Answer (score 1):

`age` is nested inside `userDetails`. Can you try:

```
db.getCollection('data').find({"userDetails.age":{$lt:50}})
```

Since it is a string you can use [JavaScript Expression](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D) for query. It will do the typecasting:

```
db.getCollection('data').find("this.userDetails.age < 50"}})
```

Comment: Why don't you make age number?

Comment: @chridam Oops!! sorry.

Comment: Great Arun , thaks , using javascript expression is working.
Do you know how to Extract all the mails of the users to a csv file?

Comment: @NatiBarchilonI I haven't checked the csv, but nested documents into csv won't easy mapping. If this solves, you can mark as answered.